# Input/output error using Vagrant & winnfsd

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04, nfs

I'm using [vagrant-winnfsd](https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd) plugin to add NFS support with Vagrant on a Windows 8.1 host. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 guest.

I'm using this setup to run a Rails app. Everything runs great except for when Rails/Carrierwave tries to delete files from the tmp dir which generates this error:

```
Errno::EIO (Input/output error @ dir_s_rmdir - /vagrant/myproject/public/uploads/tmp/1421108602-18479-5242):
```

Here's the relavent portion of my Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: are these files created from the guest or already exists on the host? any chance this is some kind of permission error?

Comment: @MichaelS File is uploaded on the host and the temp file is created by the app running on the guest

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with winnfsd: https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd/issues/22

Comment: @MichaelS Yeah I was hoping someone would have have a workaround for that

Comment: Well, I guess you don't use Virtualbox's shared folders because it's slow as hell, but what about [SMB](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html) instead of NFS?

Comment: @MichaelS I tried SMB but that was painfully slow (worse than Virtualbox's shared folders). I'm now looking into rsync as an alternative but running into bunch of problems with it as well :(

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't know that, indeed looks horrible. What about running SMB server inside the VM and connecting to it via '//<vm>'? It's not perfect, but people saying performance is good.

Comment: @MichaelS Interesting, I'll look more into it. Although it seems less than ideal as I'd have to move the files into the VM's share. If the VM crashes (which it does once in a while) I'd have to recheckout the code base, etc. In any case, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this issue by using [this approach](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/550#issuecomment-3789978) suggested in one of the GitHub tickets.

Basically it involves pointing Rails and Carrierwave to a dir outside of the /vagrant folder to dump the tmp files into in order to avoid running into any lock/permission issues:

```
# config/initializers/01_patch_tmpdir.rb

class Dir
  def self.tmpdir
    '/home/vagrant/rails_tmp/'
  end
end

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = '/home/vagrant/uploads_tmp/tmp/uploads'
  config.root = '/home/vagrant/uploads_tmp/tmp'
end

ENV['TMPDIR'] = Dir.tmpdir
```

You can now go ahead and add that file to your .gitignore so it doesn't get in the way of other people working on your project.